Next.js Provider and Session undefined error
Whenever i complie it gives me 500 error and treid to debug and i see session and provider is undefined anyway to fix it?
// Route.js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { connectToDB } from '@utils/database';
import User from '@models/user';

console.log("Google Client ID:", process.env.GOOGLE_ID);
console.log("Google Client Secret:", process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);


export const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        })
    ],
    async session({ session }) {
        const sessionUser = await User.findOne({
            email: session.user.email
        })
        session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();
        return session;
    },
    async signIn({ profile }) {
        try {
            await connectToDB();
            // Check if user already exists
            const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email });
            // If not, create a new document and save user in MongoDB
            if (!userExists) {
                await User.create({
                    email: profile.email,
                    username: profile.name.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(),
                    image: profile.picture,
                });
            }
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error checking if user exists: ', error.message);
            return false;
        }
    },

});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


//Nav.jsx
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession, getProviders } from "next-auth/react";

const Nav = () => {
    const { data: session } = useSession();
    const [providers, setProviders] = useState(null);
    const [toggleDropdown, setToggleDropdown] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const setUpProviders = async () => {
            const response = await getProviders();
            console.log('Providers fetched:', response); // Debugging line
            setProviders(response);
        }
        setUpProviders();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Session data:', session); // Debugging line
    }, [session]);

    return (
        <nav className='flex-between w-full mb-16 pt-3'>
            <Link href='/' className='flex gap-2 flex-center'>
                <Image
                    src='/assets/images/logo.svg'
                    alt='logo'
                    width={30}
                    height={30}
                    className='object-contain'
                />
                <p className='logo_text'>Promptopia</p>
            </Link>

            {/* Desktop Navigation */}
            <div className='sm:flex hidden'>
                {session?.user ? (
                    <div className='flex gap-3 md:gap-5'>
                        <Link href='/create-prompt' className='black_btn'>
                            Create Post
                        </Link>

                        <button type='button' onClick={signOut} className='outline_btn'>
                            Sign Out
                        </button>

                        <Link href='/profile'>
                            <Image
                                src={session?.user.image}
                                width={37}
                                height={37}
                                className='rounded-full'
                                alt='profile'
                            />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {providers &&
                            Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                                <button
                                    type='button'
                                    key={provider.name}
                                    onClick={() => signIn(provider.id)}
                                    className='black_btn'
                                >
                                    Sign in
                                </button>
                            ))}
                    </>
                )}
            </div>

            {/* Mobile Navigation */}
            <div className='sm:hidden flex relative'>
                {session?.user ? (
                    <div className='flex'>
                        <Image
                            src={session?.user.image}
                            width={37}
                            height={37}
                            className='rounded-full'
                            alt='profile'
                            onClick={() => setToggleDropdown((prev) => !prev)}
                        />

                        {toggleDropdown && (
                            <div className='dropdown'>
                                <Link
                                    href='/profile'
                                    className='dropdown_link'
                                    onClick={() => setToggleDropdown(false)}
                                >
                                    My Profile
                                </Link>
                                <Link
                                    href='/create-prompt'
                                    className='dropdown_link'
                                    onClick={() => setToggleDropdown(false)}
                                >
                                    Create Prompt
                                </Link>
                                <button
                                    type='button'
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        setToggleDropdown(false);
                                        signOut();
                                    }}
                                    className='mt-5 w-full black_btn'
                                >
                                    Sign Out
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {providers &&
                            Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                                <button
                                    type='button'
                                    key={provider.name}
                                    onClick={() => signIn(provider.id)}
                                    className='black_btn'
                                >
                                    Sign in
                                </button>
                            ))}
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Nav;

Tried to debug and looked if .env was casugin but everthing seems fine with .env.
Here is my what i can see in my web console
enter image description here
Here is what i can see in my terminal
enter image description here

Hi Kartik! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
